# EXSLT extension "dyn:evaluate($expr)" failing in XSLT 1.0 in TIBCO BW

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0, tibco, tibco-topic

I've been trying to implement dynamic evaluation of an expression using Exslt extension dyn:evaluate($expression) in XSLT1.0, but I'm getting the below error.

```
BW-XML-100006 Job-261000 Error in [Transform_MCIN_XML/Dyn.process/Transform XML]
The [net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException] occurred during XSLT transformation:  
net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: 
Cannot find a matching 1-argument function named {http://exslt.org/dynamic}evaluate()
caused by: ; SystemID: tibcr://; Line#: 6; Column#: -1
net.sf.saxon.trans.XPathException: 
Cannot find a matching 1-argument function named {http://exslt.org/dynamic}evaluate()
```

I'm able to do the same using saxon:evaluate($expr) in Saxon-B XSLT 2.0 engine. However I need to do this in XSLT 1.0.

How to resolve this error and implement the same in XSLT 1.0 in Tibco BW?

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

**Sample XSLT:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
 xmlns:dyn="http://exslt.org/dynamic"
 extension-element-prefixes="dyn">
    <xsl:variable name="expr" select="not(1=1)"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
   <eval>
     <xsl:value-of select="dyn:evaluate($expr)"/>
   </eval>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I don't understand why you want to restrict yourself to using XSLT 1.0 with EXSLT extension as the error message citing `net.sf.saxon.trans`  clearly indicates you use some version of Saxon 8 or 9 that should support XSLT 2.0 and Saxon specific extensions.

Comment: I'm trying to achieve this in xslt 1.0 because the date validation is simple in here(tib:validate-dateTime()). Is there any single line date validation function available in XSLT2.0?

Comment: I am not familiar with tibco and its functions. With XSLT/XPath 2.0 to check whether a string can be parsed as an `xs:dateTime` value you can check `foo castable as xs:dateTime`. That tries to parse according to the W3C schema `xs:dateTime` syntax `yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss` plus optional time zone information, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-2/#dateTime for details. For other formats you would need to write a regular expression and/or extract components and check them respectively try to construct a `dateTime`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tib:evaluate` instead of `dyn:evaluate`.

Depending on what else your BW process contains, you may need to add the namespace below to the process in order to use the tib:evaluate() function:

```
namespace=http://www.tibco.com/bw/xslt/custom-functions
prefix=tib
```

To do that you would select the process, click the "namespace registry" button, and add the namespace above.

Comment: Thanks Tom. Although this works for static conditions something like "1=1" but the same isn't working for dynamic conditions like a field value taken from the input xml. Something like checking a particular field for a specific value. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Please update the question with the actual problem you are trying to solve, rather than the solution that isn't working.

Comment: The dynamic evaluation using tib:evaluate is working. There was some issue with my bw. Resolved it now. Thanks for your suggestion.

Comment: Can you please look into the bellow link and suggest me how do implements this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21187495/iterating-over-xmls-and-dynamically-evaluating-conditions-using-xslt?noredirect=1#comment31902793_21187495